# T-SQL Count returns ALL records Instead of Subset

Tags: t-sql

trying to figure out this dumb syntax issue

```
select distinct Count(Mgr) from CarsManager
```

returns all records..should be a subset count.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Mgr, Count(*)
From CarsManager
Group By Mgr
```

You did not specify on what the subset count should be made. Given your example, I assumed it was the `Mgr` column.

If what you seek is a count of unique managers, then you can do:

```
Select Count(Distinct Mgr)
From CarsManager
```

**Difference between Count(*) and Count(SomeColumn)**

In comments, you asked about the difference between `Count(*)` and `Count(SomeCol)`. The difference isn't in performance but logic. `Count(*)` counts rows regardless of column. `Count(SomeCol)` counts *non-null* values in SomeCol.

[COUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

> > COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.

In this case of `Count(SomeCol)`, `ALL` is implied.

Comment: quick question to you also, so doing a Count(*) on all fields instead of like Count(somefield)..makes a big difference in performance?  What's the diff if I do a Count(singleField) vs. Count(*)?

Comment: Select Count(Distinct Mgr) seems clean but did not think of doing it this way...cool I will try it out

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Added information about the difference between `Count(SomeCol)` and `Count(*)`.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - Btw, you should update your question to clarify on what you are trying to count. Is it a unique list of managers? Is it a count by manager? Is it a subset of managers?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this all in one go - you need a subquery:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Mgr FROM CarsManager) as tbl1
```

Comment: quick question, I always thought subqueries are just bad....slow performance, sloppy.  What is the take on this?